# DES: (Using sbox 2) to show that Two output bits from each S-box affect middle bits of the next round and the other two affect the end bits

Tags: security, des

Data Encryption Standard (DES) algorithm : (Using sbox 2) to show that Two output bits from each S-box affect middle bits of the next round and the other two affect the end bits.

The permutation table P is defined in the following table.

```
16   7   20  21 29  12  28  17 [END BITS]
1    15  23  26  5  18  31  10 [MIDDLE BITS]
2    8   24  14 32  27   3   9 [MIDDLE BITS]
19  13  30   6  22  11   4  25 [END BITS]
```

From the table above you can see that bits 7 and 6 refer to the end bits and 5 and 8 refer to the middle bits.

However am not sure if this is correct because if we consider E table the 5,6 are end bits and 7,8 affecting middle bit. What is correct  ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't fully understand the question but your first statement about bits 7,6,5 and 8 is true, but remember that the "cascade effect" will make all the changes made by the P-table will go to the "right side" of the equation; but at the same time these will interact in the next round in the left side!

To fully understand the process check out this link: http://www.cronos.est.pr/DES.php